# Visual Studio not able to run ".lib" file?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, static-libraries

I am trying to build a project from the following  [Source Code](https://github.com/idmillington/cyclone-physics)  (it accompanies a book I am currently reading). Unfortunately, visual studio can not run a library with the name "cyclone_d.lib". I believe this is because visual studio simply can not locate the file. I have spent several hours trying to fix this problem by changing the settings in the linker and project, for example adding Additional Directories, but I have not been able to get any results.

Please let me know how I can fix this problem and compile the code.

Thank You!

Comment: You don't "run" .lib files. You run executables (.exe). If you need to test functions in a library, you need to create an application project and use the library.

Comment: What i'm doing is compiling the src code ".cpp", but it then says that it was not able to start the program "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\cyclone-physics-master\build\vs2010\.\..\lib\cyclone_d.lib"

Comment: Which indicates to me that the .cpp file you are compiling is in a library project, not an application project. You cannot run a .lib file, which is exactly what the error says. If there *is* an application project in the solution, you need to right click and make it the **"Startup Project"**.

Comment: I've selected the option "Set as StartUp Project" but I stil get the same error, I've also done it for the other projects but still does not work...

Answer (score 3):

Your link to source points only to some Unix-style source files but no VS project files. So I can only guess and give general help.

A VS solution contains one or more projects. Each project has a build target, in most cases a EXE, DLL, or static library LIB. When you have a solution that includes an project with an EXE build target set the option "**Set as StartUp Project**" at that project in the solution tree.

If you don't have an EXE change your project setup to create a Win32 executable instead a library. For this task the most simple approach is creating a new project (**Win32 Console Application** or **Win32 Project**) and add all the source files.

Comment: What I am trying to do is run the provided ".cpp" files and get some sort of output, meaning I don't actually want to create an ".exe" file.

Comment: For example, if a gave you a ".cpp" file that printed "Hello World!" all you would have to do is compile and you see the output on the terminal, this is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Please help! I know this is a very simply problem but I can't seem to get the files to run no matter what I do!

Comment: That's right. Lib files do not run, no matter what you do. Only exe files run. You must make an exe project that links in your lib file.